# Failed a "late answer" review audit. Was skipping the correct answer?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I noticed some questions in the "late answer" section and looked at them (since it's always 0 when I look at it), and the only options I had were `Looks good`, `I'm Done`, and `Skip`.

It doesn't seem there's much I could do with late answers.

So I approved it and then the system tells me I failed a test! Was the correct option to skip it?

Comment: Voting and flagging are available in the "Late Answers" review queue.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, voting and flagging are options.  If you are unsure, you skip.  If it is good, `Looks good`.  If it is bad, a down vote is needed.